# Qt/MinGW giving "no such file or directory" for header file when it exists

Tags: qt, compiler-errors, mingw, header-files

I'm trying to compile a Qt application using MinGW and version 4.8.6. The project is compillable for Qt for Embedded Linux and necessary adaptations to be compiled for Windows have already been done (and a successfull compilation like that was done years ago). Nevertheless I'm being unable to compile it because MinGW keeps getting the error "no such file or directory" for the project's header files:

[image: Error message]

This is occurring despite the fact those files are in their correct places (the exact same source tree is used in the Embedded Linux compilation) and Qt Creator does find the files without complain, as the image below shows:

[image: Qt Creator finds the files]

(If I press Ctrl+mouse click over the `include`, Qt Creator correctly opens the header file)

Trying to solve the problem, I created a Hello World Qt Widgets application in the same folder where my project is located, copied and pasted the .pro file only changing the section with HEADERS and SOURCES to include some blank `test.hpp` and `folder/test2.hpp` files and it compiled just fine. I also did some research on the web and here in SO for similar problems and, even though the error message is pretty common, other people's situations were about Linux Terminal, running executable files and finding libraries, never about the project's own source code.

So what is keeping the compiler from finding the project's source code?

Comment: What's the full path of `template` directory?

Comment: @vahancho Is `E:\EmbrasulSVN\re8k_src\trunk\main_projects\interface\re8k_interface\template`.

Comment: Did you try to clean the build directory and run qmake again? it may just be an outdated makefile...

Comment: It looks like the `E:\EmbrasulSVN\re8k_src\trunk\main_projects\interface\re8k_interface` include path is missing.

Comment: @SergioMonteleone Yes, I always do Clean All, Run Qmake, Rebuild All.

Comment: @ssbssa Unlikely; as I sad, I created another Qt project in the same parent folder, used the same .pro file with the exception of headers and source codes which I replaced with "empty" ones, and compilation ran OK.

Comment: I'm not sure what that proves if you used different headers then.

Comment: @ssbssa well it proves Qt Creator/qmake/mingw is able to find the files located in the .pro folder and subdirectories, precisely what I need to compile my project and precisely the problem that is arrising (the compiler says it can't find the files which are there)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to create a workaround that enabled me to compile my project: in the windows session inside the .pro file, I added a line specifically telling to look at the current directory for source code:

```
win32 {
    INCLUDEPATH += ./

#etc
}
```

As you may guess, that is a silly workaround since the compiler is supposed to look at the project directory as being part of the include path. Nevertheless it worked. I'm still unable to understand, though, why I'm unable to properly compile the code without this.